# Error installing TNTSearch and Laravel returning error on service provider

Tags: php, laravel, search, composer-php, full-text-search

Trying to install and use the TNTSearch package on Laravel 5.4. In my composer.json I have added:

```
"teamtnt/tntsearch": "^1.0"
```

I have then added:

```
TeamTNT\TNTSearch\TNTSearchServiceProvider::class,

'TNTSearch' => TeamTNT\TNTSearch\Facades\TNTSearch::class,
```

To my `config/app.php` but when I try and create an index with `php artisan make:console ProductIndexer` i get the error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class
>   'TeamTNT\TNTSearch\TNTSearchServiceProvider' not found

Any ideas? Note: I am not using Laravel Scout that has a driver package for TNT because I don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you are installing isn't the Laravel Scout version, it's just the search package without the Laravel Provider.

If you wanna use the Laravel version you have to install github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver.

Comment: no it didnt work, I am just trying composer dump-autoload

Comment: Remove the service provider and facade from `config.app.php` and remove `"teamtnt/tntsearch": "^1.0"` from `composer.json` and then run `composer require teamtnt/tntsearch`

Comment: Whoops, just looked into this.  That's because the package you are installing isn't the Laravel Scout version, it's just the search package without the Laravel Provider.  If you wanna use the Laravel version you have to install https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver

Comment: Right so infact I do need to use scout. Thanks very much Eric.

Comment: Can you change the answer you wrote in the comments because I want to mark it as answered but I had to use the laravel scout so this answer is wrong?!

Comment: Thanks bud all the best, may you be happy and well :)